# JS - I want to create a dropdown filter menu for my events

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to coding with JS, so I can't seem to find out how to create a dropdown filtermenu that can filter the content to show only certain events on my page.

Ask away if you need more information, this is also my 1st Stackoverflow post, so I don't know how much to include.

Thank you in advance!

**HTML**

```
<section id="events">
        <main>
            <section class="container" data-container></section>
            <template data-template>
            <article class="postListview">
                <div class="card middle">
                     <div class="front">
                <img src="" alt="">
                    </div>
                 <div class="back">
                     <div class="back-content middle">
             <h2 data-title></h2>
             <div data-text></div>
                <div data-pris></div>
                <div data-tid></div>
                <div data-sted></div>
                </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
             </article>
         </template>
        </main>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getJSON);

    let posts;
    let postTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-template]");
    let postContainer = document.querySelector("[data-container]");

    async function getJSON() {
        let jsonData = await fetch("http://www.rigmordesign.com/kea/huset/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/events");
        posts = await jsonData.json();
        visPosts();
    }

    function visPosts() {
        console.log(posts);
        posts.forEach(post => {
            let klon = postTemplate.cloneNode(true).content;
            klon.querySelector("[data-title]").textContent = post.title.rendered;
            klon.querySelector("[data-text]").innerHTML = post.content.rendered;

            klon.querySelector("[data-pris]").innerHTML = post.acf.pris;
            klon.querySelector("[data-tid]").innerHTML = post.acf.tid;
            klon.querySelector("[data-sted]").innerHTML = post.acf.sted;
            klon.querySelector("img").src = post.acf.billede;
            postContainer.appendChild(klon);
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: I made the elements show up in my DOM using JS, but I wanted to create a dropdown button / menu that can filter the elements to show only a specific location if selected (I have 4 different locations which the events are also labeled in my JSON file)